# PHPMail output labels

Tags: phpmailer, php

When the site owner receives an email based on form input, I want there to be bold labels...

Like this...

**Name:** $name

**Phone:** $phone

**Email Address:** $email

etc, etc...

But they're not displaying correctly.

**Here's the way I have the email set up...**

```
$msg  = "You have been contacted by $name with regards to $subject. Their message is as follows:";
$msg .= "" . PHP_EOL;//Line Break
$msg .= "Name:".$name . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$msg .= "Phone:".$phone . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$msg .= "Email Address:".$email . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$msg .= "Low Budget:".$budgetlow . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$msg .= "High Budget:".$budgethigh . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$msg .= "Venue Name:".$venuename . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$msg .= "Event Capacity:".$eventcapacity . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$msg .= "<strong>Event Description:</strong>".$eventdescription . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$msg .= "" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL; //Line Break
$msg .= "You can contact $name via email at $email or via phone at $phone." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
```

I want the labels to show up in bold. Above, I've added tags to ***Event Description*** to try and bold it, but it doesn't come out bold.

**Here is how I have my headers set up...**

```
$headers  = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: You've got the tag [tag:phpmailer], but are you actually using phpMailer? It doesn't look like it, but it would probably be a lot easier if you did.

Comment: The tags are capitalized. I can't change that.

Comment: that's not what I mean. phpMailer is a software product (it's a library for making it easier to write PHP code that sends emails). The tag 'phpmailer' is intended to be used for questions about that library. It doesn't look like you're using that library, so the question probably shouldn't be tagged 'phpmailer'. However, if you're not using it, I would strongly recommend that you do try it out, as it will make your life easier (eg you won't need to have any code to set up mail headers).

Comment: Now I got you. Sorry... I took you too literally.

Comment: Be careful with PHP_EOL. You're generating text intended for ANOTHER system, not your local PHP install. The PHP_EOL that php is using (let's say you're running on Windows) are useless for an SMTP server running on (say) Linux.

Comment: @MarcB Ok... do you suggest "\r\n" instead? (Not sure if I wrote that right)

Comment: The EOL thing is arbitrary anyway; you're sending HTML, so you need `<br>` tags. You also need to send it as HTML content type. There's probably quite a bit of work needed here to get it working. But as I said already, all of that would be a whole lot easier if you use phpMailer library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending a plain text email, but you're trying to make parts of it bold by including `<strong>` tags.

This won't work. A plain text email will only ever be displayed as plain text. If you want to send it with HTML markup, you need to make the whole thing into an HTML document, and send it with the HTML content type.

I would also strongly recommend using a decent PHP mailer library such as [phpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). This will make it a *lot* easier to send HTML formatted emails -- you'll be able to get rid of all the code you have to setup the headers entirely; the library will take care of all this sort of thing for you.

**[EDIT]**

Okay, just to prove how easy this is, how about I give you some code to demonstrate? Let's assume you use phpMailer. Your code would look like this:

```
//somewhere at the top of your program
require('/path/to/phpMailer.class.php');

//your existing $msg code, but with <br> tags instead of PHP_EOL
$msg = ....

//this bit replaces your header block...
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->AddReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->AddAddress('recipient@example.net');
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = $msg;

//and send it (replaces the call to php's mail() function)
$mail->send();
```

It really is that easy. Seriously. Especially if you're a beginner, you are a lot more likely to get it right doing it this way than trying to hand-code your mail header. That's just crazy.

But more importantly, it adds a whole stack of other features.

- Want to include attachements? Without the library, it would be a mountain of code. With phpMailer, it's a single extra line.
- Security. phpMailer will validate the addresses and other fields, and prevent hackers from using your system to send spam (if you're writing your own headers, the odds are strong that you're vulnerable to attack).
- Sending to multiple recipients? Just call `AddAddress` multiple times.

Comment: What you have sounds great. But, I have spent a lot of time on what I already have. Is there a way to implement one of these libraries into what I already have? **PS-** I don't know much about PHP. I'm kind of break/fixing things as I go along.

Comment: seriously, it really is easy. but just to prove it, I've thrown together some code for you. see the edited answer.